# Id da primeira tabela não carrega no BD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando criar uma agenda simples de contato com duas tabelas: Sendo uma delas `empresa :nome` e a outra `contatos :nome :telefone :email`... Criei as duas tabelas e coloquei uma Foreign_key na segunda que irá receber o empresa_id da primeira.

No formulário da segunda tabela coloquei um `f.collection_select` da seguinte maeira: `<%= f.collection_select :empresa,Empresa.order('nome Asc'),:id, :nome,{prompt: "Selecione uma empresa"},{class: "form-control"} %>` . Funciona só que quando eu seleciono a empresa e incluo os outros campos o id da empresa não salva no Banco. Poderiam me ajudar me dizendo onde estou errando?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Aparentemente está correto o `collection_select`, precisamos de mais informações: Você se importa em editar a pergunta e colocar o código do controller?

Comment: @Andrey Depois dê uma olhada nos magic links como `[pt.so]` em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1616/quais-s%C3%A3o-todos-os-magic-links-que-possu%C3%ADmos ajuda a diminuir o número de caracteres :D

Comment: @Caputo Sempre me esqueço disso =P Vou tentar lembrar nas próximas

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:empresa_id, Empresa.all.order(:nome), :id, :nome {prompt :true}) %>
```

E assim funcionou!

Comment: Bom que você conseguiu resolver seu problema, mas se possível tente explicar melhor qual era seu problema e como o resolveu, assim usuários que enfrentem problemas similares no futuro possam se beneficiar de sua resposta.

Comment: Muito bem! Apenas marque sua resposta como correta e dê mais informações de qual era o problema, como disse o @Fernando

Comment: Correto. Eram duas tabelas sendo que o select apresentava todos os campos da tabela pai. Mas no momento em que salvava os dados no BD não inseria o valor do id da tabela pai na tabela filho. Porém com esta formatação do f.collection_select o problema foi corrigido e passou a inserir o valor do id da tabela pai na tabela filho.